# Getting "IndexError" while calculating time intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

Details:

- There are two cities, a, b. and two arrays representing flight departure time.
- Flight from a to b is represented using `array a2b`, and flight from b to a is represented using `array b2a`.
- Flight from a to b and b to a both take `100 minutes.`
- `Need to take "n" roundtrips` between the two cities`(a -> b and b -> a is ONE round trip).`
- Assume you always take the `first flight from a to b` and then take the `earliest available flights.`

Question:
**Return the time you arrive back at city a.**

Example:

```
a2b = [109, 500]
b2a = [210, 600]
n = 2(roundtrips we need to take)
```

Explanation:

- Take 109 from a to b, arrive at b at 109 + 100 = 209
- Take 210 from b to a, arrive at 210 + 100 = 310.
- Take 500 from a to b again.
- Arrive at b at 500 + 100 = 600, then take 600 flight back
- Arrive at a at 600 +100 = 700.

My Code:

```
def flight_time(a2b, b2a, n):
    
    a2b.sort()
    b2a.sort()
    
    trips = 0
    a_arrival_time = 0
    
    i = j = 0
    while trips <= n:
        b_arrival_time = a2b[i] + 100
        i += 1
        
        while j < len(b2a):
            if (b2a[j] - b_arrival_time) < 0:
                j += 1
                continue
            else:
                a_arrival_time = b2a[j] + 100
                j += 1
                trips += 1
                break
      
    return a_arrival_time      

flight_time(a2b, b2a, n)
```

Error `IndexError: list index out of range`

I also get this error when n becomes large such as `n=6`.

It looks like the code is not handling all the edge cases.

Comment: `i` will become equal to `2` at the third step of the first `while` loop, thus you get an index error. You arrays are indexed `0` to `1`.

Comment: is there any other better approach to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "while trips <= n" try "while trips < n"

Comment: it is working with `while trips < n.`  is it going to pass all the edge cases?

Comment: At this time you used all the edges of the list. I mean what case could be an edge case?

Comment: I also get `IndexError` when n becomes large such as `n=6`.